# Map Multiple Tor Daemon Local Names/Addreses/Ports to Multiple Country Specific ExitNodes

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays, onion-routing

All:

Is it possible to Map Multiple Tor Daemon Local Names/Addresses/Ports to Multiple Country Specific ExitNodes without running multiple instances of the Tor daemon?

```
amazon.cn (127.0.0.1) => amazon.cn:443
amazon.fr (127.0.0.2) => amazon.fr:443
amazon.com (127.0.0.3) => amazon.com:443
```

Or

```
127.0.0.5:9095 => amazon.cn:443
127.0.0.6:9095 => amazon.fr:443
127.0.0.7:9095 => amazon.com:443
```

Or

```
127.0.0.1:9095 => amazon.cn:443
127.0.0.1:9096 => amazon.fr:443
127.0.0.1:9097 => amazon.com:443
```

A VirtualHost option would be great not consuming as many resources as running multiple daemons.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Respectfully,

Gary

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, now only dot-onion mapping is supported in the way you're describing. For a better resource consumption use one main tor instance and another ones that are just connected to it - one per mapping.